# Android Domain layer with Room Dao's and Repositories

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, clean-architecture, use-case

My project has grown to point where it makes sense to implement a domain layer.

Reading the [doc's](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/domain-layer) I would implement a use case like so.

```
class FormatDateUseCase(userRepository: UserRepository) {

    private val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(
        userRepository.getPreferredDateFormat(),
        userRepository.getPreferredLocale()
    )
    
    operator fun invoke(date: Date): String {
        return formatter.format(date)
    }
}
```

And invoke it like this.

```
class MyViewModel(formatDateUseCase: FormatDateUseCase) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        val today = Calendar.getInstance()
        val todaysDate = formatDateUseCase(today)
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Yet the Room examples i've come across led me to define my user repository like this.

```
class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {

    fun insertUser(user: User) {
        userDao.insert(user)
    }
}
```

So now my `FormatDateUseCase` has a dependancy on `UserDao` that gets instantiated by my Room database.

So my question is there a cleaner way to do this than my approach here?

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel(
    FormatDateUseCase(
        UserRepository(
            myRoomDatabase.userDao
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Either way will work. If you need to mask the specific method of user storage then repository is a better solution. Or perhaps you want to have other properties on the User object that come from another DAO, again repository would be better. It's all guidelines rather than specific "you must do this." so do whatever feels better for your use case, and/or app.I'd use repository for your example, but make UserRepository an interface (with an implementation), and use dependency injection to remove all of that construction from your use case class.

Comment: You are right. I'm wandering if I've missed the point of how to define the UseCase somewhere. My "clean-architecture" OCD likes the domain layer, though is less keen on the requirement for a deep dependancy of the Room Dao. I was hoping there is a way inject the object cleanly.

Comment: yeah, there is. The Dao should be in the data layer. define the user repository interface in the domain layer, and it's implementation in the data layer. declare the repository interface in the use case (also domain). declare the use case in the VM.

Comment: Do you have a reference to an example or the time write it up? I'm not really following your comment. Thanks

Comment: this is probably the best place to start i think https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qX6zmKY4KP0. It's not specific to you, but gives a fairly detailed look at the concepts, which should allow you to go from there. If I get some time later, I'll try to write something up as an answer

Comment: Possibly the wrong link, there is nothing about defining code structure for Domain layers with Room DB's as a data source.

Comment: like i said, its not entirely specific to you but gives you the concepts of the various layers. I've given you the specifics in a comment above.